# How to use zipWith (Reactor, Spring) in a loop?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor

I have the following problem using Spring Reactor.

What I want to do is call n sources in callbacks and collect the answer of all in one on a map.

In the first instance I did it in the following way that works:

This causes me to return a map with the value of ws1 ws2 and ws3

```
Mono<Map<String, String>> variables = Mono.just(new HashMap<>());

// WS1
            variables = variables.zipWith(
                    resourceRequest.getResourceWS1(parts[1], parts[2], mapper, tipoPersona, codigoPersona), (a, b) -> {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.putAll(b);
                        return map;
                    });

// WS2
            variables = variables.zipWith(
                    resourceRequest.getResourceWS2(parts[1], parts[2], mapper, tipoPersona, codigoPersona), (a, b) -> {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.putAll(b);
                        return map;
                    });

// WS3
            variables = variables.zipWith(
                    resourceRequest.getResourceWS3(parts[1], parts[2], mapper, tipoPersona, codigoPersona), (a, b) -> {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.putAll(b);
                        return map;
                    });
```

The problem comes when I try to do the same in a loop:

This causes me to return a map with the value of ws3 
only the last but I lose the values ​​of the others returned

logical lack that I do not include it but calls ws1 ws2 and ws3

```
Mono<Map<String, String>> variables = Mono.just(new HashMap<>());

List<String> filas = new ArrayList<String>();
        filas.add("BDP,http://180.5.60.167:8080,consultarDatosBasicos_ESP,variableResource1:variableMotor1-variableResource2:variableMotor2");
        filas.add("BDP,http://180.5.60.167:8080,consultarDatosBasicos_ESP,variableResource3:variableMotor3-variableResource4:variableMotor4");

for (String fila : filas) {

variables = variables.zipWith(
                    resourceRequest.getResource(parts[1], parts[2], mapper, tipoPersona, codigoPersona), (a, b) -> {
                        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.putAll(b);
                        return map;
                    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the static factory method `zip` instead of the fluent instance method `zipWith`: there's a variant that takes an `Iterable` of `Publishers` + a zip function that works with an `Object[]` (unfortunately, at this point we lose the type-safety of the zip function).

First, convert the list of URLs to a `List<Mono<Response>>` (eg. using `stream()` and mapping to `resourceRequest.getResource(parts[1], parts[2], mapper, tipoPersona, codigoPersona)`).

Use `Mono#zip`, and as the zip function you can iterate over the array, which will contain all the responses, and build up your map.

That will result in a `Mono<Map>`.

***PS**: if your sources were not producing a single response, you could do the same using `Flux#zip`, but keep in mind Flux variant only considers values up until the point where the first source stops emitting. So it has the size of the shorter source `Flux` basically.*